# Passing a string to a function (selectionSort), shows the error: passing argument 1 of 'selectionSort' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

I crated a function that sort **n** strings in an array. When I do not  use parameters the function works, but if I pass my array of strings (**strings**) deploy a warning: *argument 1 of 'selectionSort' from incompatible pointer type*.

I called the function in main:

```
selectionSort(strings, numStrings);
```

The function:

```
void selectionSort(char strings[], int numStrings)
{
     char sinString[25] //25 is the limit for the string
     for(int i = 0; i <= numStrings - 1; ++i)
     {
       for(int j = 1 + i; j <= numStrigs; ++j)
         if(strcmp(strings[i], strings[j]) > 0)
         {
           strcpy(sinString, strings[j]);
           strcpy(strings[j], strings[i]);
           strcpy(strings[i], sinString);
         }

     }  
}
```

Comment: `strings[i]` is a `char`, the arguments to `strcmp()` and `strcpy()` must be strings.

Answer (score 0):

`char strings[]` is an array of characters, i.e. just a single string. If you're sorting an array of strings, the first parameter should be `char *strings[]`.

```
void selectionSort(char *strings[], int numStrings)
```

Also, you're accessing outside the array in your loop:

```
for(int j = 1 + i; j <= numStrigs; ++j)
```

Change `<=` to `<`. Also, `numStrigs` is a typo for `numStrings`.

Comment: I did it, but iut deploy me : _expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[25][50]_

Comment: Sounds like `strings` is not declared correctly in `main()`, but you didn't show that in the question.

Comment: It should be `char strings[25][50]`, but you probably have `char *strings[25][50]`